# Generating a URL for Twitter users with Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have users that sign in to a Meteor app with Twitter. I'd like to create a profile page route for them with Iron Router that references their Twitter screenName.

I can't work out what should replace the `:slug` part of the Iron Router code below (there is no property `slug` in my `user` document).

```
this.route('expertPage', {
path: '/profile/:slug',
data: function() { return Meteor.users.findOne({"services.twitter.screenName": this.params.slug}); }
});
```

Comment: It's not saying that there should be a `slug` property on your user document. It's saying find the user document whose `services.twitter.screenName` property is equivalent to the `slug` parameter provided in the URL. "Slug" is just a term meaning URL-friendly keyword, i.e. some string that only contains letters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores.

Comment: @Cuberto yeah, sorry, I should've been clearer -- `slug` is my own choice of word. Might as well be `banana` or anything random. Pointing a browser to `localhost:3000/profile/cavill` works, but I want to be able to use `{{pathFor 'userProfile'}}` in my templates (which I can't currently).

Comment: Ah, perhaps you could do `{{#with slug}}{{pathFor "userProfile"}}{{/with}}` and then add a helper like `Template.someTemplate.slug = function() { return {slug: this.user.services.twitter.screenName}; };`

Answer (score 3):

First you must provide the slug as a key value pair, an object in a template helper:

```
userScreenName = function() {
  return Meteor.user().services.twitter.screenName;
}

Template.profileLink.helpers({
  slugObject: function () {
    return {'slug': userScreenName()};
  },
  screenName: function () {
    return userScreenName();
  }
});
```

You can now supply this to the pathFor helper by using

a) with a `with` block

```
<template name="profileLink">
  <a href="{{#with slugObject}}{{pathFor 'userProfile'}}{{/with}}">{{screenName}}</a>
</template>
```

b) with direct use as argument

```
<template name="profileLink">
  <a href="{{pathFor 'userProfile' slugObject}}">{{screenName}}</a>
</template>
```